# Do airlines require aptitude tests or other similar tests for new pilots?

Tags: airline-operations, flight-training, pilots, career

Do airlines require pilots to take an aptitude test? Are there any other similar kinds of tests that airlines perform?

Comment: What kind of test do you have in mind? Airlines are businesses.  Perhaps you mean airline crews, who are humans?

Comment: Many airlines also make applicants do psychometric tests as well, as in personality tests.

Comment: Perhaps someone would list the kinds of testing airlines perform, and what airlines do what types of testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they do, and so do some independent training organisations. For instance EPST markets an aptitude test called [Compass](http://epst.com/en/news/epst-selection-services/), developed to test the suitability of candidates before they engage in pilot training.

Some airlines only hire self funded students (who have paid for their own CPL, type rating etc) and they can be flight tested in the simulator.